# Linux AF_ALG Crypto API: algorithm name

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cryptography

I've registered my crypto algorithm inside kernel driver with name my-cbc(aes). It is listed in the /proc/crypto.
But when I try to use it via AF_ALG, I get ENOENT on bind, though, if I rename my algorithm both in kernel space and user space to just cbc(aes) everything works as intended and my algorithm is called.

```
struct sockaddr_alg sa = {
  .salg_family = AF_ALG,
  .salg_type = "skcipher",
  .salg_name = "cbc(aes)" // works
  .salg_name = "my-cbc(aes)" // does not work
};
```

in /proc/crypto:

```
name         : my-cbc(aes)
driver       : my-cbc-aes-dcp
module       : mxs_dcp
priority     : 400
refcnt       : 1
selftest     : passed
internal     : no
type         : ablkcipher
async        : yes
blocksize    : 16
min keysize  : 16
max keysize  : 32
ivsize       : 16
geniv        : <default>
```

But I don't want to hide existing AES implementation with same name with mine. Is there any restrictions to algorithm naming in AF_ALG?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like kernel finds my algorithm implementation, but then tries to find another with same name, although I've removed CRYPTO_ALG_NEED_FALLBACK flag in registration meta info. But during kernel source inspection I've found out that I can specify driver name (my-cbc-aes-dcp) to salg_name instead of just name, so I named my algorithm back to cbc(aes), lowered it's priority and select it via driver name.